# How to throw exception manually in Mule ESB without using java code

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I'm new to mule, please help me on this logic. Actually in my flow i have choice message processor, Expression which is not satisfy it will go to default in choice. After that i have flow reference.
I don't want message goes to default(choice) has to be populate to flow reference.Instead it has to go to choice exception strategy which i configured in that flow.
So i need to throw some exception in default.
Actually i have a very big flow, i made it simple to understand. Please find by xml config.

```
        <flow name="Choice" doc:name="Choice">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Star\Desktop\Mule\FilePath1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])')=='book']">
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Star\Desktop\Mule\FilePath2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Star\Desktop\Mule\FilePath3" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <flow-ref name="SampleService" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="*****#[exception]****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
<flow name="SampleService" doc:name="SampleService">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Star\Desktop\Mule\FilePath4" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Kindly suggest me any standard way to throw exception in Mule.I also tried keeping

```
            <test:component  throwException="true"/>
```

but it is throwing exception like -  "The prefix "test" for element "test:component" is not bound".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `test:component` you need to declare the `test` namespace, as you've done for all the other namespaces Mule uses. This said, not sure you want to use `test` elements in your production code.

One alternative is to use the `null-component` that always throws an exception when it receives a message, but this doesn't give you control of the thrown exception.

The other alternative, is to throw any exception you want from a Groovy component.

Bear in mind that exceptions are wrapped by Mule infrastructure: you'll have to use the [ExceptionUtils](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/util/ExceptionUtils.html) to dig in the stack and find the root cause.

Comment: Used groovy component with the script in this link which you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689573/how-do-i-force-an-exception-in-mule/18691490#18691490. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Validation component if you don't want to write code. Just create a new 'Is True' validator and set the expression to #[false]. On the customize page set your error and the message you want to return, I used org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException, but you can use the lookup too. Took me forever to figure this out.